# XPath parent based on several children

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

How to I select the select the parent `<tr>` with the elements containing `ccc` and `ddd` in it, and no others?

i.e. from the XML below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ddd</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
        <td>select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>select</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

select this row:

```
<tr>
    <td>ccc</td>
    <td>ddd</td>
    <td>select</td>
</tr>
```

Alternatively, how do I select the third `td` (with select written in it) on the same row of the `td`'s with `ccc` & `ddd`?

Answer (score 3):

An XPath expression contains several location steps. Each step creates a context either for a predicate (within `[...]`) or a following step. The *last* step contains the result set that is effectively selected. You can apply one or more predicates in any step, to reduce the set.

This expression selects the `tr` element which contains a `td` element with a string value of `aaa` and a `td` element with a string value of `bbb`.

```
//tr[td='aaa' and td='bbb']
```

This expression will select a *set* containing the two `td` nodes (`<td>select</td>`) from the second and third `<tr>`s (the ones that have `td='ccc' and td='ddd'`:

```
//tr[td='ccc' and td='ddd']/td[3]
```

Instead of using *and* you can also stack predicates. Each predicate reduces the result set creating a context in which the following predicate operates. This has the same effect as the above expression:

```
//tr[td='ccc'][td='ddd']/td[3]
```

Comment: That's a great explanation.  I'll give it a go and if it works, one more correct answer for you.  Thanks!